# Mysql query in java doesnt work for me but if i write this query on mysql consol it works fine

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static final StringBuilder GET_SEARCH_USER_DETAIL = new StringBuilder().
            append(" SELECT * FROM  m_user_master").
            append("WHERE M_User_Name = IFNULL(NULL,M_User_Name)AND Login_id = IFNULL('?',Login_id) ");
```

does'nt work in java.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is kind of generic. An error? An unexpected result? Which one?

Comment: @Desaroll ..this query working fine on sqlyog but when i derive this in java it is showing an sqlexception 'you have an error in sql syntax'..

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank in from of `WHERE`

```
        append(" SELECT * FROM  m_user_master").
        append(" WHERE M_User_Name = IFNULL(NULL,M_User_Name)AND Login_id = ...
```

Your generated query Looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM  m_user_masterWHERE M_User_Name = IFNULL(NULL,M_User_Name)AND Login_id...
```

That's why you get an error

Answer (score 0):

add a **blank space** in starting of second append before **where**.